# How to request rights to commit to an open source git repository?

Tags: git, github, branch, commit, pull-request

I've created a configuration file for a specific [open source project](https://github.com/KevinOConnor/klipper) that I want to integrate into the master branch.

I know that there is a whole process to go through before it gets approved and integrated into the master branch.

My question is, how do I go about requesting access to commit this file?

Comment: `how do I go about requesting access to commit this file?` you don't. Thats what pull requests are for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+contribute+open+source

Answer (score 1):

Create a Pull Request after committing your changes.

Comment: You mean, commit my changes locally to the cloned master branch? Or do I commit it to another development branch? What I'm confused about is when I try to create a pull request on github,, it asks to compare a specific branch to master.